# Wrong phrasing in defender of the unicorn instructions page

Tags: bug, winter-bash, wording, grammar

Once you reach the defender of the unicorn page, it says

> There she is! You have are almost there!

shouldn't it say either

- There she is! You are almost there!

or

- There she is! You have her almost there!

Comment: Related issue on the same page: the grammar is inconsistent, as some bullet points end with a punctuation and others don't.

Comment: All your have are almost belong to us.

Comment: [The reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum if this meme could be confirmed as the intention behind this phrase *There she is! You have are almost there!*, it would make the perfect answer.