# Grammar mistake in Sparkles the Unicorn Game

Tags: bug, winter-bash, grammar, winter-bash-2022

Page 3 of the Sparkles the Uniform Game has a grammar mistake in the second sentence of the page header:

> There she is! You have are almost there!

Presumably the word "have" was unintentional, and the header should have instead read:

> There she is! You are almost there!

Comment: see my answer question/suggestions from last year: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374537/wrong-phrasing-in-defender-of-the-unicorn-instructions-page

Comment: @CodyGray As noted by Vickel , the question you linked is for last year's game [winter-bash-2021]. This question is about the game in [winter-bash-2022], which is similar but a distinct site and game.

Comment: Yes, but it's *exactly the same problem* affecting the Winter Bash game in both years. (That's the standard for a duplicate bug report.) Obviously, they took the same wording from last year.