# Wrong phrasing in "Can you help guide Sparkles back home? " page

Tags: bug, winter-bash, unicorns, winter-bash-2022

Once you find Sparkles, the instructions page tells us:

> There she is! **You have are** almost there!

As I already mentioned [last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374537/wrong-phrasing-in-defender-of-the-unicorn-instructions-page), this should be either changed to:

- There she is! You are almost there!

or

- There she is! You have her almost there!

Comment: Well you used totally wrong tags last year, no bug tag, no winter bash even, so hopefully this year staff will notice and fix.

Comment: Grammar are overrated anyhow.

Comment: All your Sparkles are belong to us.

Comment: [Reference for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) the last comment.